# How to dynamically set the number and behavior of inputs/outputs in a neural network?

Tags: c++, neural-network

How would one implement a feed-forward neural network with a configurable number and dynamic behavior of inputs and outputs?

I am trying to add neural networks to the entities in a game I'm working on. However, for every entity type I add I have to create a new neural network with a different number of inputs and outputs, then hard-code how the inputs are set and how the outputs are used to direct behavior.

I would like to find a way to dynamically set all of this, so I don't have to rewrite a new neural net for each entity type.

As I am using C++, I currently have a vector of doubles as the input and output containers. Currently my NN algorithm iterates through every element in a layer (including the input "layer") and passes the information to the next layer, I believe this will work fine for now (though I'm open to suggestions). However, my real issue is how to have different behavior for each type of entity without limiting the number of inputs/outputs, or the types of senses/behaviors an entity is allowed to possess.

As an example, say I want to add a creature to the game that can see other creatures, smell food, bite as an attack, and move along the ground. Each eye would be an input, along with the sense of smell; biting would be an output, along with x and y movement. I would need a way to calculate the input values, and extract meaning from the output values in the neural net.

Now if I also wanted to add a creature that can smell other creatures, locate their direction from itself, shoot spines, and float through the air, I would need a different number of input and output calculations (input: smell, location; output: shoot, x, y, z movement).

I would like each entity type to have it's own neural net structure, yet have an overall standard interface for the AI system to work with when handling and iterating through each individual network. More specifically, when handling game-senses to input conversion, and output to game-behavior conversion.

I want emergent behavior from the creatures I add, so I don't know what the "correct" output will be. Because of this, I'm using a simple genetic algorithm to control weight evolution.

Since I haven't been able to find much information regarding my issue, the only idea I've come up with so far is to implement each entity's senses and behaviors as a vector of function pointers, with each function corresponding to a particular input or output. While this allows me to customize how each entity works, and retain a single system for the AI, I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of accomplishing what I want.

The process function does all of the work in the LearningSystem class:

```
void LearningSystem::process(int const last_frame_time) {
    std::set<unsigned int> const& learning_list = eManager->getAllEntitiesPossessingComponent(ComponentType::intelligence);

    vector<double> outputs, inputs;
    for (auto entity : learning_list) {
        Intelligence& intel = eManager->getComponent<Intelligence>(entity, ComponentType::intelligence);
        Sensors& sensor = eManager->getComponent<Sensors>(entity, ComponentType::sensors);
        Behavior& behavior = eManager->getComponent<Behavior>(entity, ComponentType::behavior);

        // calculate each input value
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sensor.sensor_list.size(); ++i) {
            sensor.triggers[i](sensor.sensor_list[i]);
        }

        // retrieve the inputs from the sensors...
        inputs = sensor.sensor_list;
        // ...and add the bias
        inputs.push_back(bias);

        // for each layer
        for (auto i : intel.vecLayers) {
            // clear the internal outputs
            outputs.clear();

            // for each neuron
            for (auto j : i.vecNeurons) {
                // reset the neuron value
                double neuronValue = 0.0;

                // for each weight/input pair, sum the weights * inputs
                for (auto k = j.vecWeights.begin(), in = inputs.begin(); k != j.vecWeights.end(); ++k, ++in) {
                    neuronValue += (*k) * (*in);
                }

                // store the internal outputs for use by the next layer
                outputs.push_back(sigmoid(neuronValue));
            }

            // assign the inputs for the next layer...
            inputs = outputs;
            // ...and add the bias
            inputs.push_back(bias);
        }

        behavior.values = outputs;

        // calculate actions based on output values
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < behavior.values.size(); ++i) {
            behavior.actions[i](behavior.values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am curious about other ways of implementing this idea, and if there are any resources which address this kind of issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Neural network" is a very broad term. What kind of NN architecture are you implementing?

Comment: Very unclear what you're trying to do imo. Are you just hooking up all components of an entity to an ANN? What's the expected output?

Comment: Can you somehow show us what kind of data you have? And can you tell me which kind of neural network structure you are using? As you can see that, the computation of the inverse of hessian matrix in neural network makes the adaptive learning a bit impossible, but there is smart ways.

Comment: It seems like you already implemented a preliminary design. I suggest you show some of the current code so that we may get a better grasp on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something like this a long time ago, so unfortunately I don't have the source, but I remember that I defined the structure of the network as an array that was passed to a function that would create the network. Each element of the array was an int that described the number of neurons in the network layer, so [2,3,2] for example would have created a neural network with 2 input neurons, 3 in the hidden layer and 2 output neurons. Synapses were created automatically by linking every neuron in neighboring layers. It was very simple so setting/getting values from the input/output layers was done with a function call like this

```
double getValue(int layer, int neuron);
```

Sorry this is a bit vague but that's all I can remember.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I was looking for, but it is a good idea for simplifying my design at least. And I'll probably try your 'getValue' function against my function pointer design to see which performs better. Anyway, thanks for the answer!